# mysql sum payments

Tags: mysql

can anyone help me out with one query? 
i have a DB that looks like this: 
table expenses

```
paydate       receiver   payment
2011-05-06     SOLO       3000
2011-05-08     Walmart    5000
2011-05-09     McDonalds  400
2011-05-08     Korona     700
2011-05-08     Walmart    1000
2011-05-09     BigZ       1300
```

I have to calculate the sum of all payments in the day when the max payment was done.
the result should look like this:

```
paydate       payment
2011-05-08    6700
```

i managed to find the max payment and the paydate of it:

```
SELECT payment, paydate FROM expenses WHERE payment=(SELECT max(payment) FROM expenses);
```

but it only gives me the max payment and paydate, and i need a sum of the payments on that day.

Comment: check info about aggregate functions for mysql, there is also a lot of sites with exercises for sql, e.g. http://sql-ex.ru/

Comment: `SELECT SUM(payment) as sum_payment, paydate
FROM expenses
GROUP BY paydate
ORDER BY sum_payment DESC
LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
`t1` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`t2` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`t3` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)


INSERT INTO `t` (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`) VALUES
(1, '2012-04-19', 100),
(2, '2012-04-18', 200),
(3, '2012-04-18', 300),
(4, '2012-04-19', 150);
```

and query:

```
select sum(t3), t2 from t  where t2=(select t2 from t where t3 = (select max(t3) from t))
```

result gives us 500 and 2012-04-18, i.e. sum and date

or check this:

```
select t1, sum(t3), t2 from t  where t2=(select t2 from t where t3 = (select max(t3) from t)) group by t1
```

Answer (score 7):

Change the query to this:

```
select sum(payment), paydate
from expenses 
where paydate=(
  select paydate from expenses 
  where payment = (
    select max(payment) from expenses)
);
```

where I've used the [**`SUM`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.

**EDIT**: Previous output wasn't what was required. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a62ec/2) of what I used previously and now.

Comment: You forgot about the date: `GROUP BY paydate`

Comment: @daemonfire300 I don't that'd be necessary, as there may be two/more receivers receiving *same* (and **max**) payments on different days.

Comment: Yeah but the author says: _I have to calculate the sum of all payments **in the day**_

Comment: Nope it gives me the same output, just doubles the payment

Comment: have you tried to execute your query? it's wrong, it gives us 5000 as sum instead of 5000+1000(+700?), other answer that already deleted was right

Comment: i haven't seen the answer that was deleted. i tried the one posted above

Comment: the comment was for author of answer not you

Comment: yeah, i figured : ) sorry : )

Comment: ohk, I didn't read the complete question. Thanks @llamerr and daemonfire300 for pointing it out!. Edited the reply.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the other answers did not take into consideration that there can be more than one date with the same max payment. My answer below illustrates how to return all the possible answers:

```
SELECT sum(payment) total_amount, paydate
FROM expenses
WHERE paydate in (SELECT paydate
                  From expenses
                  WHERE payment = (Select max(payment) from expenses))
group by paydate
order by total_amount desc
```

Good Luck!